# SQL INNER JOIN DISTINCT

Tags: sql, join, distinct, inner-join

I have the tables **PRODUCTS** and **LISTINGS**. When doing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM products
INNER JOIN listings
ON products.product_number=listings.product_number
```

This is the "search" functionality:

```
WHERE products.product_number !='' 
AND listings.monthly_price BETWEEN '0' AND '10'
```

This returns a double entry of one of the product listings. Why isn't **DISTINCT** working?

**EDIT**

Products:

```
product_number, make, model model_number, colour, processor, battery_standby, battery_talk, camera, flash, screen_size, screen_res, memory
```

Listings:

```
listing_number, featured, date, member_id, network, length, product_number, monthly_price, minutes, texts, data, image1
```

Essentially I'd like to create result rows matching the `listings` tables via their `PRODUCT_NUMBER` to the `product` table. It's for a search function of a phone listings website to be more precise.

To be much more specific, the search function uses the `products` table to search, then the `listings` table to show the useful information about the phone listing.

**ANSWER**

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM listings
INNER JOIN products
ON products.product_number=listings.product_number
```

The above did the trick; simply swapping the tables round. I also inserted a few more rows into `listings`, and the "problem" vanished. Even if it's not solved, it isn't happening anymore... Not sure what the problem was.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is applied to **all** columns - are **all** columns identical in the two rows you deemed "double entries" ?

Comment: DISTINCT * will return distinct permutations of all fields in both `products` and `listings` meeting your criteria. Surely you meant DISTINCT products.productId, listings.listingid or similar?

Comment: It would suggest that one of the fields your selecting is different

Comment: @Nick, There must be some difference on both the rows that's why it comes twice

Comment: The two tables have dissimilar columns. To be honest, I didn't understand either of those replies sorry!

Comment: Please show the double entry that is returned.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan in which case, how can I eliminate the extra result?

Comment: Why on earth would a primary key column allow an empty string? That first `WHERE` condition is scary as hell... not to mention that `monthly_price` is apparently a text field and not a number. Anyway, `DISTINCT` doesn't return duplicates, ever, so at least one of the field values must be different between the two rows you think are duplicates.

Comment: Added the table columns.

Comment: Because you use * all columns of both tables are returned. Which also includes the PK values for both tables which makes each row distinct from every other row by definition (because of the PK). But none of the queries really make sense (because of the distinct). What is it that you are **really** trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a record where 2 listings joins a single product then this would produce what you are seeing:

The select distinct is done on the result of the inner join

I'd use the common join value to select * from each table and see the results

HTH

Ian

Comment: I would say that even forget the SELECT *, because it is a bad idea except that 1% when you really nead everything:)

Comment: Okay thanks :) So how do I write a "common join" in this circumstance. See my comment on the below answer for more details.

Comment: Ok Nick, you are at the bottom of quite a steep learning curve, however there is lots of stuff out there to help you. When I started, I found the "for dummies" series well written and very good at explaining the essential building blocks. There is a "sql for dummies". I expect its written to the same high standard. Otherwise google introduction to building sql queries or http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp Actually SQL basics aer no too difficult, if you follow that by reading "inside SQL by Kalen Delany" or http://www.sqlserverinternals.com/ you'll then know everthing you need

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're just expecting something from `DISTINCT` that doesn't work that way....

Assume you have a table `Products` with `ID` and `Name`, and table `Listings` with `ID`, `ProductID` (FK to `Products), and`Listing_date` (just to make things a bit simpler here....)

Assume furthermore that your table `Products` has entries:

```
ID     Name
 1     Foobar
 2     Bazfoo
```

and table `Listings` has entries

```
ID    ProductID   ListingDate
 1        1         2012-01-01
 2        1         2012-03-01
 3        2         2012-04-01
```

If you join these two tables and apply a `DISTINCT`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ProdID = p.ID, p.Name, ListingID = l.ID, l.ListingDate
 FROM dbo.Products p
 INNER JOIN dbo.Listings l ON l.ProductID = p.ID
```

what results do you expect??

The result will be:

```
ProdID  Name   ListingID  ListingDate
 1     Foobar     1         2012-01-01 
 1     Foobar     2         2012-03-01
 2     Bazfoo     3         2012-04-01
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword is applied **to all columns** - only if **all columns** in the result set are identical, then a row will be filtered out.

From your comments, I'm led to believe that you're expecting that the "duplicate" product with `ID = 1` and `Name = Foobar` should be excluded. This is **NOT** the case - see the result set - if you look at all four columns, those two rows with `ProdID = 1` are **NOT** identical - therefore, they will both show up.

That's just the way the `DISTINCT` keyword is defined to work.

If you want to "filter out" the duplicate product with ID=1 - which of the two entries in the `Listings` table are you expecting to be shown in the result set?

Comment: I basically would like to create result rows matching the `listings` tables via their `PRODUCT_NUMBER` to the product table. It's for a search function of a phone listings website to be more precise.

To be much more specific, the search function uses the `PRODUCTS` table to search, then the `LISTINGS` table to show the useful information about the phone listing.

Comment: @NickPrice: Sure - but again: **which row** from `Listings` do you want to display, if you want to show only one row `ProdID=1/Name=Foobar` - there are two (here - possibly more) rows in `Listings` for that one row in `Products` - if you only want to show one row from `Products` - which one from `Listings` do you want to see and which other ones do you want to ignore??

Comment: Result for the question's query:

`37, Apple, iPhone, 4, Black`

`36, Apple, iPhone, 4S, White`

`37, Apple, iPhone, 4, Black`

I wish to remove the duplicate.

Comment: Sorry- pressed enter by accident. Not a problem formatting something like that here!

Comment: @NickPrice: for those five columns, you do have a duplicate - but that duplicate will be removed by `DISTINCT`. I'm assuming you have additional columns in the result set - no? If you select **only those five columns** and use `DISTINCT` - do you still get duplicates??

Comment: @NickPrice: look [at this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28aa6/3) - I've set up a sample table with your five columns and the data provided. If you run a `SELECT *` against it - you get three rows - if you run `SELECT DISTINCT *` against it - you only get two rows. `DISTINCT` **will** filter out duplicates - if the entire row (all columns!!!) is really a duplicate.

Comment: @marc_s what should we do if we want to remove one of the rows which includes `Foobar` in `Name` column? Any way with or without `DISTINCT`?